# Prove that $Ax = b$ with complex solution, actually is rational solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Ax = b$, a system of linear equations, $A$ is matrix of rational numbers, and this system has only one complex solution.

Prove this solution is also rational.

Can someone help me please? I prefer not only hints... thanks.

Comment: If you assume that $b$ is also rational then this follows immediately from Cramer's rule

Comment: If you don't assume $b$ is rational, here's a counterexample: $x = \pi$ (where $A = 1$).

Comment: As written, the statement is false--let $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1}$ and $\vec{b} = \pmatrix{\pi \\ e}$.  There is only one solution, it is an element of $\Bbb C^2$, but the solution is not rational.  You must assume something about $\vec b$.

Comment: if b is rational, how can you prove it by Cramer's rule? A is not necessarily n x n .

Comment: @ChenR: Any non-redundant (finite) linear system with a _unique_ solution has to be a Cramer system (in particular with square coefficient matrix). So given that there is a unique solution, you can simply drop some equations that are linear combinations of the others, and be left with a square system for which Cramer's rule applies.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394223/linear-equations-real-solution-rational-solution).