A question on system of linear equations.
Let $A$ be a $3×4$ matrix and $b$ be a $3×1$
matrix with
integer entries. Suppose that the system
Ax=b has a complex solution. Then which statements are true?

Ax=b has an integer solution
Ax=b has a rational solution
The set of real solutions to Ax=0 has a
basis consisting of rational solutions.
If b = 0, then A has positive rank.

My attempt:
4. True Since Rank 0 => b = 0.
1,2.  Az = b => A $\overline{z}$ = b,
=> A (z + $\overline{z}$) = 2b
=> There exists a real solution.
I don't have a way to verify the existence of Integer or Rational solutions.
3.I need Help.

To be clear: Do both $A$ and $b$ have integer entries?

Yes Both A and B has integer entries

For 1, assume your first row is  $\begin{bmatrix} 2 &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the first entry of $b$ to be $1$. Then the first equation will be $2x_1=1$, which has no integral root. You can choose other rows suitably to ensure your matrix has complex root as in the hypothesis.  I think (2)+(3) was explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394223/system-of-linear-equations-having-a-real-solution-has-also-a-rational-solution
